# How to use Istio's Prometheus to configure kubernetes hpa?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

We have an Istio cluster and we are trying to configure horizontal pod autoscale for Kubernetes. We want to use the request count as our custom metric for hpa. How can we utilise Istio's Prometheus for the same purpose?

Comment: You can use custom metrics from Istio's Prometeus for the Kubernetes HPA. I'll try to reproduce this case and return to you with an answer.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Have you able to reproduce this?

Comment: sorry for delay, I'll reply soon

Answer (score 4):

This question turned out to be  much more complex than I expected, but finally here I am with the answer.

1. First of all, you need to configure your application to provide custom metrics. It is on the developing application side. Here is an example, how to make it with Go language: [Watching Metrics With Prometheus](https://mycodesmells.com/post/watching-metrics-with-prometheus)
2. Secondly, you need to define and deploy a Deployment of the application (or a Pod, or whatever you want) to Kubernetes, example:

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: podinfo
   spec:
     replicas: 2
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: podinfo
         annotations:
           prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: podinfod
           image: stefanprodan/podinfo:0.0.1
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           command:
             - ./podinfo
             - -port=9898
             - -logtostderr=true
             - -v=2
           volumeMounts:
             - name: metadata
               mountPath: /etc/podinfod/metadata
               readOnly: true
           ports:
           - containerPort: 9898
             protocol: TCP
           readinessProbe:
             httpGet:
               path: /readyz
               port: 9898
             initialDelaySeconds: 1
             periodSeconds: 2
             failureThreshold: 1
           livenessProbe:
             httpGet:
               path: /healthz
               port: 9898
             initialDelaySeconds: 1
             periodSeconds: 3
             failureThreshold: 2
           resources:
             requests:
               memory: "32Mi"
               cpu: "1m"
             limits:
               memory: "256Mi"
               cpu: "100m"
         volumes:
           - name: metadata
             downwardAPI:
               items:
                 - path: "labels"
                   fieldRef:
                     fieldPath: metadata.labels
                 - path: "annotations"
                   fieldRef:
                     fieldPath: metadata.annotations
   ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: podinfo
     labels:
       app: podinfo
   spec:
     type: NodePort
     ports:
       - port: 9898
         targetPort: 9898
         nodePort: 31198
         protocol: TCP
     selector:
       app: podinfo
   ```

   Pay attention to the field `annotations: prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'`. It is required to request Prometheus to read metrics from the resource. Also note, there are two more annotations, which have default values; but if you change them in your application, you need to add them with the correct values:

   - `prometheus.io/path`: If the metrics path is not /metrics, define it with this annotation.
   - `prometheus.io/port`: Scrape the pod on the indicated port instead of the pod’s declared ports (default is a port-free target if none are declared).
3. Next, Prometheus in Istio uses its own modified for Istio purposes configuration, and by default it skips custom metrics from Pods. Therefore, you need to modify it a little.
   In my case, I took configuration for Pod metrics from [this example](https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-prom-hpa/blob/master/prometheus/prometheus-cfg.yaml) and modified Istio's Prometheus configuration only for Pods:

   ```
   kubectl edit configmap -n istio-system prometheus
   ```

   I changed the order of labels according to the example mentioned before:

   ```
   # pod's declared ports (default is a port-free target if none are declared).
   - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
     # if you want to use metrics on jobs, set the below field to
     # true to prevent Prometheus from setting the `job` label
     # automatically.
     honor_labels: false
     kubernetes_sd_configs:
     - role: pod
     # skip verification so you can do HTTPS to pods
     tls_config:
       insecure_skip_verify: true
     # make sure your labels are in order
     relabel_configs:
     # these labels tell Prometheus to automatically attach source
     # pod and namespace information to each collected sample, so
     # that they'll be exposed in the custom metrics API automatically.
     - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
       action: replace
       target_label: namespace
     - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
       action: replace
       target_label: pod
     # these labels tell Prometheus to look for
     # prometheus.io/{scrape,path,port} annotations to configure
     # how to scrape
     - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
       action: keep
       regex: true
     - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
       action: replace
       target_label: __metrics_path__
       regex: (.+)
     - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
       action: replace
       regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
       replacement: $1:$2
       target_label: __address__
     - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
       action: replace
       target_label: __scheme__
   ```

   After that, custom metrics appeared in Prometheus. But, **be careful with changing Prometheus configuration**, because some metrics required for Istio may disappear, check everything carefully.
4. Now it is time to install [Prometheus custom metric adapter](https://github.com/directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter).

   - Download [this](https://github.com/directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) repository
   - Change the address for Prometheus server in the file `<repository-directory>/deploy/manifests/custom-metrics-apiserver-deployment.yaml`. Example, `- --prometheus-url=http://prometheus.istio-system:9090/`
   - Run command `kubectl apply -f <repository-directory>/deploy/manifests`
     After some time, `custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` should appear in the output of a command 'kubectl api-vesions'.

   Also, check the output of the custom API using commands `kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq .` and `kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/*/http_requests" | jq .`
   The output of the last one should look like in the following example:

   ```
   {
     "kind": "MetricValueList",
     "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
     "metadata": {
       "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/%2A/http_requests"
     },
     "items": [
       {
         "describedObject": {
           "kind": "Pod",
           "namespace": "default",
           "name": "podinfo-6b86c8ccc9-kv5g9",
           "apiVersion": "/__internal"
             },
             "metricName": "http_requests",
             "timestamp": "2018-01-10T16:49:07Z",
             "value": "901m"    },
           {
         "describedObject": {
           "kind": "Pod",
           "namespace": "default",
           "name": "podinfo-6b86c8ccc9-nm7bl",
           "apiVersion": "/__internal"
         },
         "metricName": "http_requests",
         "timestamp": "2018-01-10T16:49:07Z",
         "value": "898m"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

   If it does, you can move to the next step. If it doesn’t, look what APIs available for Pods in CustomMetrics `kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq . | grep "pods/"` and for http_requests `kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq . | grep "http"`. MetricNames are generating according to the metrics Prometheus gather from Pods and if they are empty, you need to look in that direction.
5. The last step is the configuring HPA and test it. So in my case, I created HPA for the podinfo application, defined before:

   ```
   apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
   kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
   metadata:
     name: podinfo
   spec:
     scaleTargetRef:
       apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
       kind: Deployment
       name: podinfo
     minReplicas: 2
     maxReplicas: 10
     metrics:
     - type: Pods
       pods:
         metricName: http_requests
         targetAverageValue: 10
   ```

   and used simple Go application to test load:

   ```
   #install hey
   go get -u github.com/rakyll/hey
   #do 10K requests rate limited at 25 QPS
   hey -n 10000 -q 5 -c 5 http://<K8S-IP>:31198/healthz
   ```

   After some time, I saw changes in scaling by using commands `kubectl describe hpa` and `kubectl get hpa`

I used instruction about creating Custom Metrics from the article [Ensure High Availability and Uptime With Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler and Prometheus](https://dzone.com/articles/ensure-high-availability-and-uptime-with-kubernete)

All useful links in one place:

- [Watching Metrics With Prometheus](https://mycodesmells.com/post/watching-metrics-with-prometheus) - the example of adding metrics to your application
- [k8s-prom-hpa](https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-prom-hpa) - the example of creating Custom Metrics for Prometheus (the same as in the article above)
- [Kubernetes Custom Metrics Adapter for Prometheus](https://github.com/directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter)
- [Setting up the custom metrics adapter and sample app](https://github.com/luxas/kubeadm-workshop#deploying-a-custom-metrics-api-server-and-a-sample-app)